# Help with a proof in Hungerford's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I didn't understand a detail in this proof of this theorem:

[image]
[image]

The definition of content:

[image]

I didn't understand why $C(C(f)f_1C(g)g_1)\thickapprox C(f)C(g)C(f_1g_1)$

I need help only in this part.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p\in D[x]$ and if $a\in D$, then $C(af)=aC(f)$. (Why?) If you apply this for $a=C(f)C(g)$ and $p=f_1g_1$, then you obtain the equality $C(C(f)f_1C(g)g_1)=C(f)C(g)C(f_1g_1)$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: yes, of course. thank you very much